# Why do I still have a margin around my body on mobile?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am learning the basics of responsive design, and started from scratch. I want a very simple page with no margin on the sides. Yet on an iphone, the site has still a fairly big white margin left and right. This is the CSS i have so far:

```
    div#header_image img{
        max-width:100%;
    }
    div#chart img{
        max-width:100%;
    }
    div#Chart_place{
        margin-bottom:2em;

    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
        div#container{
            width:800px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
        div#container{
            width:max-width;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }   
    }

    body{
        font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        margin:0;

    }
    h1{
        font-size: 1.5em;
        margin-top:2em;
        margin-bottom:2em;
    }
     ul{background-color:white;}
     div#Feesboek_button{
    }
    input[type='text'], textarea {font-size:16px;}
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: can you share a link or complete code on jsfiddle.com

Comment: You just have to replace `width: 800px` by `width: 100%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT/UPDATE:** Since my previous answer is not what you where looking for, use this:

```
html,body { margin:0; padding: 0; }

#container {
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;

  /*for ilustration purposes*/
  background-color: #f13700;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

There you go, no margins on 800px or less.

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/fCzT9/
Full screen: http://jsfiddle.net/fCzT9/embedded/result/

---

*Previous answer:*

In your CSS you have:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    div#container{
        width:800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will be applied for every device with a screen that is at least `800px`. You have declared the width with a fixed `800px` and `margin: 0 auto` will center that container with `800px` in the screen. Take into account that your device might have a high density screen (called Retina in iPhones).

The solution to your problem depends on how your layout is based, but try this:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    div#container{
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 80em;
        margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This way, the maximun width will be 80 times the base font-size, 16px, resulting in 1280px. As the width is declared with 100%, it will take the available width in the screen. If the screen is bigger than 1280px, it won't go beyond it since it's the max-width.

Note: If you are not using `box-sizing: border-box`, if you add `padding` to the class which already has  `width:100%`, the padding will be added as an extra to the element's resulting width which will cause it to go beyond the max-width and in small screens you will be able to side scroll your pages = not good.

Comment: But on a screen with a resolution of minimum 800px (a computer screen) I don't want the site to fill the whole screen! Only on the screens with smaller than 800 px I want no margins...

Comment: Then use 50em instead of 80em. 80em will only fill screens with 1280px or less. Screens with 1680px or 1920px won't be filled.

Comment: I have updated my answer and added a demonstration on jsfiddle. I hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your time, but still on an iphone, I still have a pretty big white margin around the container!

Comment: I chanced the media query to max 1000 px and now it works! Didn't know the iphone had that big screen...

Comment: @KasperVanLombeek yes, that's why I said "Take into account that your device might have a high density screen (called Retina in iPhones)" in the answer. These are high density screens. For example, the iPhone 5S has a display of 1136-by-640 resolution with
326 ppi. You can also target by dpi or ppi with the media querys instead of width. I'm glad I was of help. :)